# Ubuntu - win 8.1 dual boot - ssd and uefi woes

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, ssd, bootloader

I built my new computer last week and decided it was about time I installed my dual boot. I disconnected the gpu as I was getting an out of range issue with the monitors, presumably as a result of not having the drivers yet. I then messed with bios so I could boot from the usb device, and clicked to install. This is when I encountered my problem, I got a message about uefi and another os installed with bios compatibility mode. I have since gone through and tried both methods but on the next step it fails to detect any operating systems, and does not let me choose the "install alongside" option. Should I select uefi mode and manually partition?

I have never had an ssd or uefi bios before so I do not know how to deal with this. Help is appreciated!

ps. in case it is important, I want to use burg bootloader. Don't know if it is relevant or not!

edit 1:  I have run ubuntu without installing and run the command as suggested in the comments. The output is as follows: 
3.19.0-15-generic

when I was installing windows 8.1 I did so using a usb flash drive that was created using Microsofts tool. I installed it to a samsung 850 EVO ssd. I wish to use this same ssd to boot ubuntu, and I have created an empty partition in advance. I have an hdd which will be used for swap and main storage. I do not have secure boot turned on.

My motherboard is an asus z97-a and I have epu, tpu and ezxmp switched on.

When installing windows 8.1 pro I did not get the option of selecting anything relating to uefi or traditional bios mode. At least as far as I can recall. I have had no trouble with windows so far. Please continue to advise.

still need advice.

I have resintalled windows. It does not give me the option to select legacy or uefi, but changing the settings using the uefi bios utility on my machine from legacy first to uefi only / uefi first windows seems to have detected this and installed correctly.  I now have my dual boot working.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: It wasn't preinstalled, I built it and installed windows 8.1 myself.

Comment: And it is the latest version of ubuntu.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, open a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and add the output of `parted --list&&lsb_release --short --codename&&uname --kernel-release` if you didn't follow Microsoft's recommendations on how to install and *please* also edit your existing comments instead of adding more...   **;-)**

Comment: You will need to be more descriptive

Comment: So you want me to try ubuntu without installing then. I will do that shortly.

Comment: You really need to install both Windows & Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode not BIOS. If you really want BIOS, then you have to install both in BIOS mode. But that is installing a 4 cyl putt-putt engine to run your new hot-rod. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI And with UEFI, if you want a nice gui boot loader you need http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/ You do not want burg as it is obsolete.

Comment: I didn't think I had installed win 8.1 in legacy but I have. I now need to know how to change my windows 8.1 to uefi mode. That seems to be a question for another place so I will leave this question open until I find out if I can get this working, then mark it solved or delete it as appropriate.

Comment: Both Ubuntu & Windows install in same mode as you boot install media. Or you have to boot in UEFI mode to install in UEFI mode. And Windows will totally repartition drive as it only boots from MBR(msdos) with BIOS and only form gpt(GUID) with UEFI.

Comment: How do I mark this solved?